# Session Cookie HttpOnly Set After Initial Server Response Showing as Vulnerable

Tags: cookies, session-management, web-scanners

Is a session cookie set without HttpOnly at first, but added before the client browser finishes rendering, still considered vulnerable?  The scanner test I need to satisfy believes so, but is this a false positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to test.  After the browser finishes rendering,  open the JavaScript console and try this:

`alert(document.cookie)`

If you can't access the session id using the terminal,  then an attacker cannot access it using XSS.